# Not able to access the attribute of another div in HTML page using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, html

I am trying to pass value `quest.quesId` and `questionOption.name` to `function checkScore`. But it is coming as undefined(questionId, optionName). If the same line is put inside `ol` then I am able to get the quest.quesId but this would not suffice the purpose.

**HTML page**

```
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat="quest in questionJson" value={{quest.quesId}}>
        {{ quest.question }}

        <div>
            <label ng-repeat="questionOption in optionJson" ng-if="questionOption.quesId == quest.quesId">
            <input type= "radio" value = "{{ questionOption.name }}"  name="radio{{questionOption.quesId}}">
                {{ questionOption.option }}
           </label>

        </div>

        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
<button type="submit" ng-click="checkScore(quest.quesId, questionOption.name)"> Check Score </button>
```

**JS page**

```
var qnaModule = angular.module("qnaModule", []);

qnaModule.controller("qaCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.questionJson = [{
        "question": "What's your name?",
        "quesId": 1
    }, {
        "question": "When was the universe form?",
        "quesId": 2
    }]

    $scope.optionJson = [{
        "option": "A",
        "quesId": 1
    }, {
        "option": "B",
        "quesId": 1
    }, {
        "option": "C",
        "quesId": 1
    }, {
        "option": "D",
        "quesId": 1
    }, {
        "option": "ABC",
        "quesId": 2
    }, {
        "option": "XYX",
        "quesId": 2
    }, {
        "option": "XYZ",
        "quesId": 2
    }, {
        "option": "PQRS",
        "quesId": 2
    }]

    var answerJson = $scope.answerJson = [{
        "quesId": 1,
        "answer": "A"
    }, {
        "quesId": 2,
        "answer": "XYZ"
    }]

    $scope.checkScore = function(questionId, optionName) {
        console.log(questionId);
        console.log(optionName);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why single Check Score button for multiple questions?

Comment: There are more functionality to be added. After attempting the questions check score will calculate combined score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know whether this code helps,

```
    var qnaModule = angular.module("qnaModule", []);

qnaModule.controller("qaCtrl", ['$scope',function($scope) {

    $scope.questionJson = [{
        "question": "What's your name?",
        "quesId": 1
    }, {
        "question": "When was the universe form?",
        "quesId": 2
    }];

    $scope.optionJson = [{
        "option": "A",
        "quesId": 1
    }, {
        "option": "B",
        "quesId": 1
    }, {
        "option": "C",
        "quesId": 1
    }, {
        "option": "D",
        "quesId": 1
    }, {
        "option": "ABC",
        "quesId": 2
    }, {
        "option": "XYX",
        "quesId": 2
    }, {
        "option": "XYZ",
        "quesId": 2
    }, {
        "option": "PQRS",
        "quesId": 2
    }];

    $scope.answerJson = [];

    $scope.checkScore = function(answerObject) {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.questionJson.length; i++) {

            console.log(answerObject[$scope.questionJson[i].quesId].answer);
        }

    };}]);
```

and HTML as follows,

```
<div  ng-app="qnaModule"  ng-controller="qaCtrl">
<ol >
    <li ng-repeat="quest in questionJson">
        {{ quest.question }}

        <div>
            <label ng-repeat="questionOption in optionJson" ng-if="questionOption.quesId == quest.quesId">
                <input type= "radio" ng-model="answerJson[quest.quesId].answer" value="{{questionOption.option}}">
                {{ questionOption.option }}
                <br/>
            </label>

        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
<button ng-click="checkScore(answerJson)">Check Score</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `quest.quesId`, `questionOption.name` will work only inside the `li` tag. Try giving click function in the input type checkbox field and capture the questId and option value and then pass to button function.

Also your input value is wrong, it should be **questionOption.option** not **questionOption.name**. Please correct in the button click function also.